# How to prevent a DDoS on AJAX endpoints?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, security

I try to wrap my head around how to really secure ajax calls of any kind that are publicly available.

Let’s say the JavaScript on a public page (so no user authentication of any kind) contains an AJAX call to a PHP script (REST API or just a script, it doesn’t matter) that does a lot of heavy lifting. So any user can just look into the source code, find the AJAX call, rebuild and execute it, and execute it again a million times in a second and DDoS your site that way - not so great.  At first I thought a HTTP_REFERER check could be helpful, but as any header field, also this is manipulable (just use a curl request) so the gain of security wouldn’t be too high.

The next approach was about a combination of using session ids, cookies, etc. to build some kind of access key for every page viewer and when someone exceeds the limit the AJAX call would run into an error. Sounds great so far, but just by cleaning the cookies, etc. everything will be reseted. So also no real solution. But, of course! Use the IP! Great idea! Users in public networks, that use only one IP for internet access will be totally happy, if one miscreant will block the service for all of them by abusing the call... not. So, also no great solution.

So, I’m really stuck here and can’t think of any great answer for my problem.

I also thought about API keys, or something alike. But that is an information that is also extractable from the JavaScript source. So how to prevent other servers using your service in a proxy kind of manner serving your data to their users? (e.g. you implemented the GMaps API in your website (or any other API) and someone uses your script accessing the API with your key)

**tl;dr**

Is there any good way to really secure your publicly viewable AJAX calls from abusing them for DDoSing your site, presenting your data on other sites, etc.

Comment: You may want to look into JWT's.  JSON Web Tokens are an open, industry standard for representing claims securely between two parties.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're overthinking what AJAX is. When your site makes an ajax request, server side, it's the same as any other page request (even if some scripts are more process intensive). You need to protect your entire site, and not just specific scripts. If your server does not have any DDoS protection, it can be attacked through any page. Look into services like [CloudFare](https://www.cloudflare.com/ddos/)

Comment: Agreed. If there are any particular requests that cause high CPU or resource usage on your server, protect these with a CAPTCHA or rate limit per IP (note rate limit, not block).

Answer (score 0):

As @Sage Mentioned it is similar to normal http request. You can use normal authentication as the http headers/cookie information will be passed on to the server every time you make ajax call. For clear view you can look into developer console on browser.  Its the same as exposing you website root url. Just make sure you have authentications checks for ajax calls too.